# Finding Billable and Non-Billable hours for best client of each month in each year

Tags: mysql

### Orginal Question

I need to determine clients with the highest profitability from a data set. So far, what I have gotten gives me a mix of results. The billable column shows hours, non-billable being empty. All clients instead of best for each month. Etc.

This is my current query I have been working on. It is the one that I have actually made it show billable and non-billable hours in the same row.

```sql
Select
    date_format(date, '%Y-%m') AS "yearMonth", 
    ClientNumber AS "Client Number",
    Sum(Case When BillType = 'Billable' Then Hours End) As "Billable Hours",
    Sum(Case When BillType = 'NonBillable' Then Hours End) As "Non-Billable Hours",
    Sum(Hours) As "Total Hours",
From Towson
WHERE ClientID
Group By
    yearMonth
Order By
    yearMonth;
```

This is what it produced:

| yearMonth | Client ID | Billable Hours | Non-Billable Hours | Total Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | 3670 | 28846.93 | 25539.88 | 54386.81 |
| 2019-02 | 3670 | 31763.55 | 19631.36 | 51394.91 |
| 2019-03 | 3983 | 35347.79 | 20010.64 | 55358.43 |
| 2019-04 | 1373 | 30674.63 | 22797.92 | 53472.55 |
| 2019-05 | 3670 | 25599.79 | 26535.00 | 52134.79 |
| 2019-06 | 3670 | 23992.33 | 25159.50 | 49151.83 |
| 2019-07 | 3244 | 25710.52 | 28995.55 | 54706.07 |
| 2019-08 | 3670 | 26738.45 | 23201.93 | 49940.38 |
| 2019-09 | 3670 | 28192.16 | 21243.57 | 49435.73 |
| 2019-10 | 3670 | 28682.27 | 24676.72 | 53358.99 |
| 2019-11 | 1691 | 18651.72 | 27537.36 | 46189.08 |
| 2019-12 | 3824 | 19286.49 | 29229.77 | 48516.26 |
| 2020-01 | 2174 | 28427.96 | 27706.00 | 56133.96 |
| 2020-02 | 3670 | 33946.23 | 20179.19 | 54125.42 |
| 2020-03 | 3670 | 35047.99 | 22220.25 | 57268.24 |
| 2020-04 | 2722 | 29763.41 | 23876.59 | 53640.00 |
| 2020-05 | 1174 | 25515.83 | 24374.23 | 49890.06 |
| 2020-06 | 2722 | 30021.44 | 25017.45 | 55038.89 |
| 2020-07 | 1439 | 27714.53 | 28563.12 | 56277.65 |
| 2020-08 | 2729 | 27126.38 | 22998.78 | 50125.16 |
| 2020-09 | 1961 | 29645.68 | 25191.37 | 54837.05 |
| 2020-10 | 1691 | 27744.36 | 26797.16 | 54541.52 |
| 2020-11 | 2169 | 22059.87 | 29683.95 | 51743.82 |
| 2020-12 | 2322 | 23738.35 | 33736.25 | 57474.60 |
| 2021-01 | 2650 | 29637.70 | 25209.81 | 54847.51 |
| 2021-02 | 1695 | 34480.73 | 20855.44 | 55336.17 |
| 2021-03 | 3670 | 41603.98 | 23543.83 | 65147.81 |
| 2021-04 | 3670 | 35361.13 | 24019.48 | 59380.61 |
| 2021-05 | 3670 | 28771.33 | 25878.61 | 54649.94 |
| 2021-06 | 1871 | 32794.82 | 27563.97 | 60358.79 |
| 2021-07 | 3670 | 30380.52 | 30440.34 | 60820.86 |
| 2021-08 | 2729 | 32588.25 | 27409.70 | 59997.95 |
| 2021-09 | 2729 | 33993.61 | 27454.88 | 61448.49 |
| 2021-10 | 2729 | 31623.98 | 27394.12 | 59018.10 |
| 2021-11 | 2729 | 27583.85 | 32724.24 | 60308.09 |
| 2021-12 | 2729 | 25785.88 | 35991.05 | 61776.93 |

So it is correct on the year Month part since it shows 36 months, however, it is adding each month together and not choosing the top client. This is the main issue I have had (other than getting non/billable to the same row).

### Update

After help from **FanoFN**, I changed the query up up a little as the same client was populating each month/year as it was always being used as it as row 1. This way it would give the totalAmount as row 1 each month.

```sql
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m') AS "yearMonth",
    ClientId AS "Client ID",
    COUNT(DISTINCT EmployeeId) AS "Employees on account",
    SUM(CASE WHEN BillType = 'Billable' THEN Hours END) AS "Billable Hours",
    SUM(CASE WHEN BillType = 'NonBillable' THEN Hours END) AS "Non-Billable Hours",
    SUM(Hours) AS "Total Hours",
    SUM(TotalAmount) AS "Total Amount",
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m') ORDER BY SUM(TotalAmount) DESC) AS RowNum
FROM Towson
GROUP BY
    yearMonth, ClientId
ORDER BY
     yearMonth, TotalAmount)
    
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE RowNum=1;
```

The output I got from this is below (only first three months shown):

| yearMonth | Client ID | Employees on account | Billable Hours | Non-Billable Hours | Total Hours | Total Amount | RowNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | 1624 | 12 | 2241.00 | null | 2241.00 | 701093.4100 | 1 |
| 2019-02 | 1624 | 11 | 1627.25 | null | 1627.25 | 532556.7200 | 1 |
| 2019-03 | 3913 | 11 | 1417.50 | null | 1417.50 | 415419.5300 | 1 |

I am getting nulls for non-billable because these clients didn't have any non-billable hours (checked through my dataset).

Comment: You can add `ELSE` into your `CASE` expression to return non-null, something like this `SUM(CASE WHEN BillType = 'NonBillable' THEN Hours ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m') AS "yearMonth",
    ClientNumber AS "Client Number",
    SUM(CASE WHEN BillType = 'Billable' THEN Hours END) AS "Billable Hours",
    SUM(CASE WHEN BillType = 'NonBillable' THEN Hours END) AS "Non-Billable Hours",
    SUM(Hours) AS "Total Hours",
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m') ORDER BY SUM(Hours) DESC) AS RowNum
FROM Towson
GROUP BY
    yearMonth, ClientNumber
ORDER BY
    yearMonth) 

SELECT *
 FROM cte 
  WHERE RowNum=1
```

1. Add `ClientNumber` in `GROUP BY` for your existing query.
2. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to give row number order by total hours descending.
3. Wrapping the main query in common table expression (cte) then filter
   using `ROW_NUMBER()` result.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rue2vWBd)

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this is going to work for me. I changed it up a little as it was only giving me the same client as that client was always row 1.